# How Integrate Ionic 3 and Angular Material?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I am trying to integrate and run Ionic 3 with Angular Material , but failed to do this.
...
Anyone can tell me how to add a third party to Ionic.
and how to run Angular Material in Ionic Framework.
.....
what I did is the Following::

-I installed `@angular/material, @angular/cdk` and `@angular/animations` .

*-adding `copy.config.js` file in the config folder* 
with the Following ::

> copyMaterialThemeCSS: {
>       src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'],
>       dest: '{{WWW}}/assets'   }

-*Edit in `Package.json`* Add the Following :

> "config": {
>       "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"   }

-in Index.html I added this Line :

```
<link href="assets/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

-Finally, when adding any component from Angular Material I am getting this Error :

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:138867:128
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:138869:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:135975:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:147347:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.218 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:116:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.195 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:96:70)
```

...

thank you in Advance.

Comment: If you are having a specific problem please ask it with examples of the work you did, otherwise your question will be closed as it is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this answer from youtube and solved my problem :

> check if the package.json has the following entries for Angular Material and the Angular CDK packages: 
>   -"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
>   - "@angular/material": "^5.2.4"
>    if you see a version above 5.2.4 and you're using angular 5 try to 'downgrade' it using those commandes 
>   => npm uninstall @angular/material --save 
>   then 
>   npm install @angular/material@5.2.4 --save 
>   and for CDK use 
>   : => npm uninstall @angular/cdk --save then npm install @angular/cdk@5.2.4 --save﻿